# Firebase: How to access a child by passing the key?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
questions
 -KkXXZkVBjaNwnnPtRzU
   date: 
     "19052017"
   question: 
    "Q9"
   uid: 
    "WAX6aezrBzXuXW3RtnnSApMazRb2"
```

This is the database structure at the moment. I'm writing a code to delete the node based on the submitted key, in this case `KkXXZkVBjaNwnnPtRzU`. I've obtained the key using the `getKey()` method and now I want to use the `removeValue()` on an `DatabaseReference` object to which I'm passing the key as the reference.

How would I go about doing that?

I should mention that the current key value I'm passing is a string. Is something like this possible at all? Basically the same principle as passing the value to a `child()` method, but instead of accessing a child of the node, I'd go for its key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("questions");

myRef.child("KkXXZkVBjaNwnnPtRzU").removeValue();
```

It's simple as that. Of course, instead of hardcoding the values, you should use String which you've obtained previously.

Comment: Didn't even occur to me this would work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user1938007 No problem! You can mark this question as answered :)